# What is the difference between "My sole is tickling" and "My sole is ticklish"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

According to my research, "**My sole is tickling**" refers to "**uncomfortable feeling**" or a very little pain like an ant bites you or so, while "**My sole is ticklish**" refers to a sensation that makes you laugh like someone rubs your sole and tends to be more comfortable than uncomfortable.

And thus, "**My sole is tickling**" tends to be a bad feeling while "**My sole is ticklish**"
tends to be a good feeling.

That is my research, but I am not so sure because I am not a native speaker.

What is the difference between "**My sole is tickling**" and "**My sole is ticklish**"?

Comment: We don't usually say things like "my sole is **tickling**", because the verb *to tickle* usually means "to tickle *someone else*", like "I am tickling my younger brother."  It's not impossible to use it the way you've used it, but it's uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

I think **"My sole is tickling"** means it is currently happening since *-ing* word forms are usually a **present participle**. However, **"My sole is ticklish"** means that it is a *daily occurrence* and it means your foot is usually ticklish all the time.

Comment: Almost. If we say that a person or a body part is **ticklish**, it means that they are particularly sensitive to being tickled and will writhe and giggle when it happens (which they may or may not find enjoyable).

Answer (score 0):

**"My sole is tickling"** means it is currently happening because *-ing* word form a **present continuous**. However, **"My sole is ticklish"** means that your foot is sensitive and is usually ticklish all the time (whenever something touches it).